# Could I force switching portrait/landscape view on emulator?

Tags: android, screen, orientation, landscape, portrait

Could I force changing the view's orientation in order to test how the layout appears or it is not possible to test this behavior on virtual device.

Under forcing it, I mean for example on click event to change from one to another screen orientation and inverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ctrl+F11` will switch the screen orientation, but when it come to coding the orientation to change you have a couple of options:

- Hardcode the `Activity` to be a given orientation. Which is useful when you want to force the user to use a specific orientation only.
- Set the `Activity` to allow either orientation and let the user decide.

Each of these is useful in their own scenarios.  For example, viewing a graph that will only be useful in landscape should be hardcoded, but scrolling through a list could allow a user to pick which was more comfortable for them.

How to set the mode:

- In Eclipse go to the AndroidManifest->Application Tab, Select the
  `Activity` you want to edit and set the `Screen Orientation`
  directly.
- In `AndroidManifest.xml`: 
  `<activity android:screenOrientation="[fill in preference here]" />`
- In code:
  `Activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_[type])`
- To get the current orientation in code:
  `Activity.getRequestedOrientation()`

An explanation of the different modes can be found here: [Screen Orientation Types | Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen)

So, if you want to force a change on a screen based on user input, you can all you need to do is set the orientation type in code.

Answer (score 2):

This is done with the HOME(7) button on the num pad (num lock needs to be disabled i beleve, not sure tho).

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `Ctrl+F11` keyboard shortcut or as the user dragon112 has suggested you can go for numpad key "7" with numlock "on".